# trimming the start and end of a video

Tags: node.js, react-native, video-processing

I am creating my first react native app so still learning.
I run a karaoke show that goes for 4 hours. I record the video and then upload it to my server.

I want to give users of my app the ability to find where they are singing and then trim the start and end of the 4 hour video so they can save a copy of just them singing.

With React Native I want to display the video with a slider underneath so uses can cue up the start of the footage they want and also controls to trim the start and finish.

when submitted, the start and end position will be returned.
Next question would be whether to trim the video server side or client side.
I am guessing that that is normally done server side
I know it's a very broad question but I just need to be pointed in the right direction of where to start. any external libraries or APIs must be free.

Running my own Nodejs server

I Googled but didn't find what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg-kit-react-native?activeTab=readme is the thing ur looking for when u want encode on phones.

You just need the start and end position with this u can create over ffmpeg a new video.

Now to the second part: your video is 4 h also big so i would first  work with a smaller version as proxy and get timestamps of your customer with that i would render a new video on server and send to the user.

On Sever is also ffmpeg the key u need looking for.